# Continue when task in celery chunks fails

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery

I need to fetch millions of ids from a remote server. I do not want to create millions of tasks at once, because each fetch creates several another tasks and it could quickly overwhelm our queue (I am unable to create a new queue).

I found out, that I could use `celery.chunks`. This would create a moderate amount of parallel tasks.

```
FetchIdTask().chunks(milions_of_ids, 50000).apply_async()
```

The problem I face now is that the fetch isn't reliable and sometimes returns 404. And when this happens the whole chunk fails and remaining tasks won't be executed.

Is it possible to somehow continue when one of the tasks in a chunk fails?

Comment: The easy answer is of course, to not fail on 404. Any reason that's not possible?

Comment: Because the task should fail when called normally from other places - for us to see it in the logs. Of course I could create a wrapper task or task which accepts chunks of ids, but I thought there might be some elegant solution without creating another tasks or changing old code

Comment: The elegant solution would be to wrap that code in an exception handler that logs the same error information to the logs and adds the failed ID to a failure list that gets inserted as new task once all ID's in the chunk are processed.